# Java array exception in this specific case

Tags: java

why this:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 20   i need to input 20 type double numbers depending on K,if k is 0 all 20 should be random between -10 and 20 if not,they have to be calculated by this :A[i] = A[i-1]

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Random;


public class Ld3151rdb258 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double A[] = new double[20];
        int K, i;
        double C;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("Andris Osītis IRDBD03 151RDB258");  
        System.out.print("K=");
        try {
            K = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("input-output error");
            return;
        }

        if (K==0) {
            Random r = new Random();
            for (i=1; i<20; i++)
                A[i] = r.nextFloat()*30-10;
        }
        else
            for (i=0; i<20; i++);
                    A[0] = 0.5;
            for (i=1; i<20;i++ );
                    A[i] = i-1*K/3.0d ;

        System.out.println("A:");
        for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%.1f\t", A[i]);
            if (i==9) System.out.println();
        }

        for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
            C = A[i];
            A[i] = A[19-i];
            A[19-i] = C;
        }

        System.out.println("\nA:");
        for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%.1f\t", A[i]);
            if (i==9) System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
for (i=0; i<20; i++);
    A[0] = 0.5;
for (i=1; i<20; i++);
    A[i] = i-1*K/3.0d;
```

Neither of these loops is doing what you think. Since each one ends with a semicolon (`for(...);`), the body of the loop is empty, and the next statement is always evaluated once, after the loop completes. That causes a problem here:

```
for (i=1; i<20; i++);
    A[i] = i-1*K/3.0d;
```

The (empty) loop repeats, until `i` is 20, at which point it exits. Then, it evaluates `A[i] = i-1*K/3.0d;` with `i` being 20, causing the error, since the highest valid index in `A` is 19.

To put it another way, what you wrote is equivalent to this:

```
for (i=0; i<20; i++){
    //Do Nothing
}
A[0] = 0.5;

for (i=1; i<20; i++){
    //Do Nothing
}
A[i] = i-1*K/3.0d;//i is now 20, which throws the exception
```

As an aside, the first loop seems unnecessary, since you only ever set one index with it. You could simply remove that loop, and just have `A[0] = 0.5`. Or change it so that it uses `i` as the index.

I'd strongly recommend that you get an IDE or editor which automatically indents your code. Problems like this will become immediately clear with correct indentation.  As another way to keep yourself safe, don't declare variables outside of the scope where they're needed. The problem here is a runtime error, rather than an easier compile time error, because you declared `i` at the top of the function. If you instead write each of your loops as `for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)`, then trying to use `i` outside the loop would be caught immediately.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i=1; i<20;i++ ); //<-- here
    A[i] = i-1*K/3.0d;
```

You have a semicolon `;` at the end of the `for` causing it to do nothing 20 times, then you try to accesso `A[i]` when `i = 20` causing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score -1):

Let's concentrate on this line:

```
for (i=1; i<20;i++ );
```

What do you think is the value of `i` after it exited the loop?

Hint: it is 20.

After that loop you're executing this:

```
A[i] = i-1*K/3.0d;
```

As you already know `i` is 20 and the array size is 20 as well with the indices 0 to 19. So this is the root of your problem. Well not exactly, you *real* problem is each `;` after the `for` loops here:

```
for (i=0; i<20; i++);
```

and here:

```
for (i=1; i<20;i++ );
```